# Find a basis for $U\cap V$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $$a = (0,2,3,-1)^T \quad b=(0,2,7,-2)^T \quad c = (0,-2,1,0)^T \quad u = (1,2,0,1)^T\quad v = (2,2,1,2)^T$$
> Let $U= \langle a,b,c \rangle, V = \langle u,v\rangle$
>
> Then a) find a basis for $U$ and $V$, b) find a basis for $U\cap V$.

I have solved a) and found a basis $\{a,b\}$ for $U$ and $\{u,v\}$ for V. But How can I combine this information to find a basis for $U\cap V$?

I have tried:

Let $x \in U\cap V$, then $x = \lambda_1 a+\lambda_2 b = \mu_1u+\mu_2 v$.
Solving $\lambda_1 a + \lambda_2 b - \mu_1 u - \mu_2 v = 0$ results in

$$\lambda_1 = -2r\quad \lambda_2 = r\quad \mu_1 = -2r\quad \mu_2 = r\quad (\forall r \in  \mathbb{Q})$$

This means $a,b,u, v$ are lineair dependent. But now what? I know I can remove one basisvector and this would result in set of independent basis vectors, but doesn't that break the spanning property?

I'm somewhat confused, could someone **clarify**, **no** solutions please.

Comment: Why do you think it will break the spanning property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have two ways of expressing your vector $x$ in terms of a single arbitrary value $r$. Since $x$ was arbitrary any element of the intersection has this form. So use one of the two ways to find a fixed vector $w$ such that your arbitrary $x = rw$ for some $r$. As a check to your work so far, you should get the same $w$ from using either $a, b$ or from $u, v$, (up to a constant multiplier). Now can you figure out what the basis of $U \cup V$ is?

Comment: I have just found it, thanks. I was thinkig about it all wrong. Solving $x=\lambda_1 a+\lambda_2 b = \mu_1 u+\mu_2 v$ doesn't result in information about basis vectors. But gives the general form of the elements in $U\cap V$. Any $x = r(-2u+v) \in U\cap V$. So $\{ -2u+v\}$ is a basis for $U\cap V$. And so is $-2a+b$.

Comment: That is best of all, to catch where your thinking went wrong before someone else points it out. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [Zassenhaus algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zassenhaus_algorithm). It gives you not only a basis for $U\cap V$ but also for $U+V$.